# Moving button stops click event happening

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a button, contained in a panel, with a click event, that works fine. However when a users presses another button, I need to move this button into another panel (this is actually a panel with a modalpopupextender), so I this code to do so:

```
newPanel.Controls.Add(buttonPanel)
```

It all get's moved and looks fine. However now when the button is clicked it doesn't fire the associated event. I have tried re-adding the event in the page_init, with this code

```
((Button)this.FindControl("serverModalSave")).Command += new CommandEventHandler(modalSave_Click);
```

But with no luck. How can I get this button to fire it's click event when moved, and why does it stop working when it's moved?

**EDIT:**

This Button needs to be added to a panel specified by the user at run time, so there is not a way to determine where the button will go in advance.

I could instead of moving this button, create a new one, but because this button is not created in the page_init I am having issues getting that to fire an event either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of moving the button, have another button on the other panel set to hidden.

Hide the button you wanted to move and show the hidden one when needed.

Moving the control changes the naming hierarchy and now the button can't be found and the click event can't fire.

This is due to how the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) works. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976) is a good (if somewhat dated) article about how view state works - if you understand this, you will understand what went wrong.

Comment: That's the issue I have, the panel that the button get's added to will vary at run time, there is no way to know in advance which panel it will need to be added to, so I have to move it. The other option is to dynamically add a new button to the panel, but then I have issues getting the event to fire on that as well.

Comment: @Sam - If you have all the information for creating the button, can't you _recreate_ it on the other panel?

Comment: that was the other option, but because I am creating the button on a button click, rather than in the page_init, then I have issues with the event firing then as well, for this new button

Comment: @Sam - I wish you had posted all of this in the question. Can you edit and _add_ all of this (very pertinent) information to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the button in the new panel, when this button is then clicked do you re-create it in the postback ?

You must re-create all controls on each postback see [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)